# Web Performance: Cycling through same 4 img src making too many requests

Tags: javascript, html

For the sake of learning I am trying to build a simple image carousel.

The current code has an array of urls that get cycled through, to update the background image of a div

```
var urls = [
    ‘/assets/img/topcatchimage/top-catiimg01.jpg’,
    ‘/assets/img/topcatchimage/top-catiimg02.jpg’,
    ‘/assets/img/topcatchimage/top-catiimg03.jpg’,
    ‘/assets/img/topcatchimage/top-catiimg04.jpg’
];

setInterval(changeBackground, 3000);

var i = 0
function changeBackground () {
    if (i == 4) { i = 0 }
    document.getElementById('mainvisual').style.background = `url(${urls[i]})`
    i++
}
```

For some reason unknown to me, this is resulting in 6-8 requests total; two-ish for each of the images. After the images have been requested twice, they are no longer sent for with new requests.

Is there a way to load these images in memory and use them without making a request every time?

Comment: Checkout me answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it is requested only ones per image.

**Example**

```js
var urls = [
  'https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg',
  'https://www.wonderplugin.com/videos/demo-image0.jpg',
  'https://www.samcodes.co.uk/project/geometrize-haxe-web/assets/images/xseagull.jpg.pagespeed.ic.iK66EGA15-.jpg',
  'https://www.elastic.co/assets/bltada7771f270d08f6/enhanced-buzz-1492-1379411828-15.jpg'
];

setInterval(changeBackground, 500);

var i = 0;

function changeBackground() {
  if (i == 4) {
    i = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('mainvisual').style.backgroundImage = `url(${urls[i]})`;
  i++;
}
```

```css
#mainvisual {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainvisual"></div>
```

But if in your case it is loaded more than once, than instead of changing background just create a div and show and hide it.

**Here is an working example**

```js
var urls = [
    'https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg',
    'https://www.wonderplugin.com/videos/demo-image0.jpg',
    'https://www.samcodes.co.uk/project/geometrize-haxe-web/assets/images/xseagull.jpg.pagespeed.ic.iK66EGA15-.jpg',
    'https://www.elastic.co/assets/bltada7771f270d08f6/enhanced-buzz-1492-1379411828-15.jpg'
];

setInterval(changeBackground, 500);

var i = 0
function changeBackground () {
    if (i == 4) {
      i = 0;
    }
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
    for (var x of images) {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
    var image = images[i];
    if (typeof image === "undefined") {
      var newImage = document.createElement("div");
      newImage.className = "image";
      newImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${urls[i]})`;
      document.getElementById("mainvisual").appendChild(newImage);
    } else {
      image.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    i++;
}
```

```css
.image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainvisual"></div>
```

Comment: Cool that does work thanks. I see, so as long as you keep the individual elements alive, the image data is kept there and not requested?

Comment: @DanielThompson in theory browser downloads content one time and keep it till you close a tab or a window or refresh the page. If it comes to images it often caches them and do not download again wih refresh. But in practice not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a preloader function and then pass a callback to execute once all is loaded:

```
function preload(arr,callback){
    var img = new Image();
    img._count = 0;
    img.onload = function(){
        if(++this._count === arr.length){
            callback && callback();
        } else {
            img.src = arr[this._count];
        }
    }
    img.src = arr[0];
}
```

you provide this function the urls (arr) and a callback (your function) once all is preloaded. So all together:

```
var urls =[
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/LEXICON/master/lexiconLogo.png",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/LEXICON/master/img/distribute.gif",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/LEXICON/master/img/dash.gif"
];

//callpreloader
preload(urls,callback);

//preloader
function preload(arr,callback){
    var img = new Image();
    img._count = 0;
    img.onload = function(){
        if(++this._count === arr.length){
            callback && callback();
        } else {
            img.src = arr[this._count];
        }
    }
    img.src = arr[0];
}

//your function
function callback(){
    setInterval(changeBackground, 3000);
    var i = 0
    function changeBackground () {
        if (i == 4) { i = 0 }
        document.getElementById('mainvisual').style.background = `url(${urls[i]})`
        i++
    }
}
```

A fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/L347w43y/

I should also perhaps mention that you cannot purely control the caching behavior by the browser. On the client side chrome has the `meta`-tags that allow you to specify the `cache-control` headers. But for instance in the jsfiddle I posted, check both request and response headers, where you will see that the fiddle request header contains `Cache-Control no-cache`. Since cache-control header is unidirectional, the response headers from github also specifies 300s on the returned images. So bottom line: the solution I propose works, as long as the headers do not override the desired behavior.

To verify what I said, make a local html copy of the script and run it there. Except for the failed requests, succesful ones will be cached (for 5 mins since github sends that Cache-control header also)

Comment: I noticed that, on my computer at least, I still see the requests happening twice with this technique

Comment: This is due to the cache-control headers specified both ways in the fiddle. The solution I propose in truth works.  Check my updated answer.